# Empty rows when creating pdf using jsPDF and jsPDF autotable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I am creating a pdf file using jsPDF and jsPDF autotable but the created pdf file is empty. There are no errors, I have checked the rows if empty but they are not.
I do not know why its empty when it is 43-pages long [the pdf file generated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83hOU.png)

here is my code:

```
$scope.export = function(){

        var columns = ["Name", "Cellphone", "Work Phone"];
        var rows = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
            rows.push({ employeename:$scope.data[i].employeename, cell_phone:$scope.data[i].cell_phone, work_phone:$scope.data[i].work_phone});
        }

        var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
        doc.autoTable(columns, rows);
        doc.save('jspdf-test312.pdf');
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved it! I have been pushing an object inside a list. It should be a list within a list.

```
$scope.export = function(){

    var columns = ["Name", "Cellphone", "Work Phone"];
    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
        rows.push([ $scope.data[i].employeename, $scope.data[i].cell_phone, $scope.data[i].work_phone]);
    }

    var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt');
    doc.autoTable(columns, rows);
    doc.save('jspdf-test312.pdf');
}
```

Comment: So, the autotable team made a bad strategy to build a table, by the way, thank you!
Solved for me, +1.